# Java MigLayout stretch as BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

Please, is there any option in MigLayout to stretch some element 100% of the JPanel size? Like when you add JButton into JFrame using BorderLayout? Thanks.

Code:

```
Jframe frame = new JFrame();  
frame.setLayout(new MigLayout());  
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());  
mainPanel.add(new JButon());
```

I want the JButton to fill entire area of JFrame. JButton is only reference object I used to explain what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "grow" for this. This should do same as border layout adding in centre.

See miglayout cheat sheet below

http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());  
        mainPanel.add(new JButton(), "dock center");
        // or 
        //mainPanel.add(new JButton(), "dock center");

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add JPanel to JFrame, than JButton to this JPanel using grow, Jbutton is only small in upper left corner...

Comment: Also look at "dock" which also works as border layout. Can't suggest more until I see the code. Have used miglayout quite a bit so can certainly help.